# polygons not appearing on map again after being hidden by setMap(null)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My problem is that I have to hide and show polygons on demand. I can hide them via `setMap(null)`, but then they don't appear back when I `setMap(map)` them.

I have checked the scope, global vars. I can't find out why is it doing so.

```
polygon[i] = new google.maps.Polygon({
                            paths:  polygonCoordinates,
                            strokeColor: "#000",
                            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                            strokeWeight: 2,
                            fillColor: "#ff44dd",
                            fillOpacity: 0.15
                        });
                        polygon[i].setMap(map);
                        polygonCoordinates.splice(0,polygonCoordinates.length);
```

Comment: Can you show the full code? What about the `map` variable? Is it correctly defined within the scope you use it?